# Laisant’s recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, derangements

Laisant’s recurrence relation is a formula which is as follows:

$$\left(n-1\right)A_{n+1}=\left(n^{2}-1\right)A_{n}+\left(n+1\right)A_{n-1}+4\left(-1\right)^{n}$$

Where $A_n$ are menage numbers.

A proof of this formula has been given [here](http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/mwoltermann/Dorrie/8.pdf).

In page 3,I have a problem with $C$-arrangements,I don' understand what exactly is going on,can someone explain it better?

Answer (score 1):

A C-arrangement takes the form

$$M_1F_1X_1F_2X_2\ldots F_nX_nF_{n+1}\;.\tag{1}$$

Suppose first that $X_1=M_{n+1}$, so that $(1)$ becomes

$$M_1F_1M_{n+1}F_2X_2\ldots F_nX_nF_{n+1}\;.\tag{2}$$

If we now remove the first couple, $M_1F_1$, from the arrangement, what remains is the arrangement

$$M_{n+1}F_2X_2\ldots F_nX_nF_{n+1}\;.\tag{3}$$

We can rotate it around the table one place to the right to get

$$F_{n+1}M_{n+1}F_2X_2\ldots F_nX_n$$

and then renumber couple $n+1$ as couple $1$ to get

$$F_1M_1F_2X_2\ldots F_nX_n\;,$$

which is a C-arrangement, but this time of only $n$ couples: $M_1$ sits to the left of $F_1$, and exactly one of the other men sits next to his wife. By definition there are $C_n$ such arrangements, so the case $X_1=M_{n+1}$ contributes $C_n$ C-arrangements of $n+1$ couples. Moreover, each C-arrangement of $n+1$ couples in which $X_1=M_{n+1}$ is uniquely derivable from one of these $C_n$ C-arrangements of $n$ couples.

Now suppose that $X_1\ne M_{n+1}$. One of the $n$ men $M_2,M_3,\ldots,M_{n+1}$ is sitting next to his wife. Looking at $(1)$, we see that $M_{n+1}$ is not sitting to the right of his wife, because $M_1$ is in that seat, but he could be sitting to the left of $F_{n+1}$. And if it’s any of the men $M_2,M_3,\ldots,M_n$ who is sitting next to his wife, he could be sitting on either side of her. Thus, there are $2n-1$ possibilities:

- $M_2$ sitting on the left of $F_2$ or $M_2$ sitting on the right of $F_2$;
- $M_3$ sitting on the left of $F_3$ or $M_3$ sitting on the right of $F_3$;
- ... and so on through
- $M_n$ sitting on the left of $F_n$ or $M_n$ sitting on the right of $F_n$, making a total of $2(n-1)$ possibilities;
- and finally $M_{n+1}$ sitting on the left of $F_{n+1}$.

In each of these cases we can again remove the first couple, leaving

$$X_1F_2X_2\ldots F_nX_nF_{n+1}\;,$$

where $X_1\ne M_{n+1}$. This is an arrangement of $n$ couples in which exactly one man is sitting next to his wife. If $M_2$ was sitting to the left of $F_2$ originally, the new arrangement is

$$M_2F_2X_2\ldots F_nX_nF_{n+1}\;,$$

and $M_2$ is the only man sitting next to his wife: $M_1$ was the only other man sitting next to his wife originally, he is now gone, and since we’re assuming at this point that $X_1\ne M_{n+1}$, the departure of the first couple did not cause any other man to be seated next to his wife.

If $M_2$ was sitting to the right of $F_2$ originally, he still, is and we have the arrangement

$$X_1F_2M_2\ldots F_nX_nF_{n+1}\;,$$

in which he is the only man sitting next to his wife.

And so on through all $2n-1$ possibilities: in each case we end up with an arrangement of $n$ couples in which exactly one man is sitting next to his wife, i.e., a B-arrangement. By definition there are $B_n$ such arrangements, and there are $2n-1$ ways to choose which man is sitting next to his wife and on which side of her, so the case $X_1\ne M_{n+1}$ contributes $(2n-1)B_n$ C-arrangements of $n+1$ couples. And every C-arrangement of $n+1$ couples in which $X_1\ne M_{n+1}$ is uniquely derivable from one of these B-arrangements of $n$ couples.

Thus,

$$C_{n+1}=C_n+(2n-1)B_n\;.$$

By the way, there’s a small error on p.494 of Lucas’s *Théorie des nombres’ from your earlier question about this result: in the little table of initial values below formula $(5)$ the correct value for $\nu_4$ is $5$, not $1$. The exposition to which you’ve linked here avoids the type that Lucas was counting with the numbers $\nu_n$, folding it into the count of A-arrangements from B-arrangements, so it has only $A_n$ (Lucas’s $\lambda_n$), $B_n$ (Lucas’s $\mu_n$), and $C_n$ (Lucas’s $\rho_n$).

Comment: Why do we need to remove the first couple $F_{1}M_{1}$?,besides in $B$-arrangement,do we have just one man sitting next to his wife?

Comment: @user715522: By definition a B-arrangement is one in which exactly one man sits next to his wife. We remove the first couple because we’re trying to count B-arrangements of $n+1$ couples in terms of arrangements of $n$ couples, so as to get recurrences for the numbers $A_n,B_n$, and $C_n$.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott,how removing these couple does not change the arrangement? I'm saying that because in all of the C-arrangements on $n+1$ couples we have the first couple

Comment: @user715522: It **does** change the arrangement: it reduces it to an arrangement of $n$ couples. That’s the whole point: we want to count arrangements of $n+1$ couples **in terms of arrangements of** $n$ **couples**, so as to develop recurrences that we can then solve. But we know exactly **how** it changes the arrangement. For instance, $(2)$ becomes $(3)$.